# No error output after installing all LAMP components

Tags: php, error-handling, lamp, ubuntu-10.04

Today I installed LAMP on my Ubuntu 10.04.
I created separate VH file for my site. When I started playing with code I noticed, that there are no errors. Some times code didn't appear, but no error message. I got curious and started to search, what might cause such behaviour. After 2h of searching I still don't have answear.

Can anyone help? If there is need for more info I will be glad to add.
I hope I asked question at right place. I have some doubts, that it should be at serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit `php.ini`, specifically [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), also, you might want to try php's function [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: @Eugene: did you restart the apache2 server?

Comment: @Eugene if not - `sudo apache2ctl restart` or `sudo service apache2 restart` should to the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Try enabling display_errors in your PHP scripts:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

In any case, any actual errors should be logged to your error log file, which in my Ubuntu install sits in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, or the error log files defined by your virtual hosts configuration in Apache.
If setting `display_errors` to true solves your issue, you can change it in `php.ini`, which you will find as specified by `phpinfo()`.

More about this and the differences between `error_reporting`, `display_errors` and `log_errors` can be found at [the appropriate php.net man page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting).

Comment: @Eugene, I think the `"true"` needs to be just `true` or `1` or `"on"`, but you just posted that with no explanation, is that the solution or is that in your code already?

Comment: @Eugene: What do you mean? Setting `error_reporting` to true or setting the level of errors displayed to `E_ALL` won't show anything if `display_errors` is not set to true.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes php.ini fix helped to solve the problem. I didn't know about it, since I worked usually in Windows with XAMPP and I didn't have such problems there.